# Simplify $xyz’w’+xy’zw+xyz’w+xy’z’w’+xy’z’w+zw’xy’$

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Simplify $xyz’w’+xy’zw+xyz’w+xy’z’w’+xy’z’w+zw’xy’$
>
> ( ` = not)

Using a karnaugh map I found that it's equal to $xy'+xz'$, but I can't find how to get there with simple algebraic simplifications.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice that all of the terms have an $\,x?$ Did you notice that each term with a $\,w\,$ has a corresponding term which is the same except with a $\,w'?$

Comment: @Somos
Yes but i'm not sure how this help.
I can get $f(x,y,z,w)=x(yz’+y’z+y’z’)$ this way, how do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f(x,y,z,w) = xyz'w + xyz'w' + xy'zw + xy'zw' + xy'z'w + xy'z'w'.$$
Then,

\begin{align}
f(x,y,z,w) 
&= x(yz'w + yz'w' + y'zw + y'zw' + y'z'w + y'z'w')\\
&= x( yz'(w + w') + y'z(w + w') + y'z'(w + w') )\\
&= x( yz' + y'z + y'z')\\
&= x( (y + y')z' + y'(z + z') )\\
&= x(z' + y').
\end{align}
The steps are justified by distributivity (which apparently you are already used to) and the laws:
$$a+a'=1\quad\text{and}\quad a1=a,$$
for each $a$, and the usual idempotence, commutativity and associativity.
I suppose you can fill in these justifications.

Comment: Thanks, the last step was what I was missing.

Comment: @paxtibimarce You're welcome. You mean, using idempotence to repeat $y'z'$ and enable to eliminate both $y$ and $z$, right? Good luck!